# Using multiple loggers in the same namespace with clojure.tools.logging

Tags: logging, clojure, logback

I'm using [clojure.tools.logging](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging), which is using the [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) factory to instantiate a [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) logger.

What I'd like to do is be able to is have my DAO namespaces log normal messages to the application log, but log all SQL queries to a query log.

Looking at the [clojure.tools.logging code](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/logging/impl.clj#L78), this doesn't really look possible, but I'm hoping that someone can prove me wrong. :)

If clojure.tools.logging can't do this, can anyone suggest another logging facility that can accomplish what I want? Or is it possible to do the routing in Logback's config files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to specify this, using the [last two forms](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/logging.clj#L70) of the `log` macro. I haven't tried this, only checked the code.

[EDIT]

Here is a [sample](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging/blob/master/src/test/clojure/clojure/tools/test_logging.clj#L79) from the test harness:

```clj
(log "other.ns" :debug e "foo")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for your eagle-eyed reading of the source! I'd like to provide my logback config and a sample of the code I used to accomplish this, but I'm not sure of the current Stack Overflow best practise. Should I submit a new answer with my stuff in it, edit my question with an update on how I did it, or something else entirely?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I don't know what the best practice is, either. I guess adding a new answer should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

[ivant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24078049/58994) is spot-on; I'm just adding this answer to document what I did for anyone else out there who may want to do something like this.

First, I created a new **Query** appender in my `logback.xml`:

```xml
<configuration>
  <appender name="Query" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>logs/query.log</File>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <!-- Things logged to this logger should *not* also go to the root logger -->
  <logger name="query" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="Query"/>
  </logger>

  <!-- root logger uses this appender, details not important -->
  <appender name="App" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <!- ... -->
  </appender>
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="App"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Second, I wrote a little macro in my `foo.db.util` namespace:

```clj
(ns foo.db.util
  (:require [clojure.string :refer [join]]
            [clojure.tools.logging :refer [log]]
            [korma.core :refer [as-sql]]))

(defn format-query [query & args]
  (let [bind-str (->>  args
                       flatten
                       (filter #(not (nil? %)))
                       (join " "))]
    (str (as-sql query)
         (when-not (empty? bind-str) (format " :: [%s]" bind-str)))))

(defmacro log-query [q & args]
  `(log "query" :debug nil (format-query ~q ~@args)))
```

Now, I can log queries like this:

```clj
(ns whatever
  (:require [foo.db.util :refer log-query]
            [korma.core :refer :all]))

(defentity foo)

(let [ids [1 2 3]
      q (-> (select* foo)
            (fields :bar :baz)
            (where {:id [in ids]}))]
  (log-query q ids)
  (select q))
```